# Numberfield to time in Crystal 10

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm new to crystal so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.  I've got a database field in Sage ERP which is the time, stored as a GMT time, the field type is number.  So for example the data in the filed will be 8461110 (08:46) or 13021054 (13:02).  Now in crystal I need to convert this field to time because I need to select data between 2 times.  I've struggled with this yesterday for the whole time, but no luck.

I've created a formula field with the following code but the result I get is 00:00:00

```
Local NumberVar TheHour;
Local NumberVar TheMin;
If Len(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}))  = 8 Then
    TheHour = ToNumber(Left(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}),2))
else
   TheHour = ToNumber(Left(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}),1));

If Len(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}))  = 8 Then
    TheMin = ToNumber(Mid(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}),3,2))
else
   TheMin = ToNumber(Mid(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}),2,2));
Time(TheHour,TheMin,00);
```

**What am I doing wrong, why is the result 00:00:00?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are missing this `:`. In  crysal reports whenever you want to assign a value to a variable syntax would be `:=`. So your formula will be

```
Local NumberVar TheHour;
Local NumberVar TheMin;
If Len(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}))  = 8 Then
    TheHour := ToNumber(Left(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}),2))
else
   TheHour := ToNumber(Left(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}),1));

If Len(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}))  = 8 Then
    TheMin := ToNumber(Mid(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}),3,2))
else
   TheMin := ToNumber(Mid(ToText({ICHIST.AUDTTIME}),2,2));
Time(TheHour,TheMin,00);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!